# Is there any reason to use FCM upstream messages?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp

Can't we just pass the message over HTTP to the app server without going through the FCM server?

Answer (score 0):

One reason is if your app server is blocked by the ISP or country of the user. But Google/Firebase is (in most cases) not blocked, and it's not possible for the ISP to specifically block your FCM upstream messages without blocking all of Firebase. So sending upstream messages through FCM bypasses the block.